# ListView with multiple Adapters and SectionIndexers

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, sectionindexer

I have an activity that contains a `ListView` that can be populated by different adapters. 
Every adapter that may populate the list is an instance of a specific class, and every one of those classes implements the `SectionIndexer` interface.
I have enabled `FastScroll` in my listview, and it works fine the first time I use `ListView.setAdapter(Adapter X)`. However, when I use `ListView.setAdapter(Adapter Y)`, It still uses the previous adapter's `SectionIndexer` (Adapter X).
How can I "reset" the `ListView`'s `SectionIndexer`?